# Ubuntu Mail Server: create default mail folders

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, dovecot

Now I have the mail server working IMAP mode. I'm interested in configure the mail server in order to set default mail folders (like Inbox, Trash and Sent folders) per mail account.

Is there a way or command in Ubuntu to deal with it? Thanks in advance.

Pd.. My mail server workas with dovecot and postfix.

Comment: Downvoting because the question doesn't show any research or effort.

Comment: Ok, I respect your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add

```
lda_mailbox_autocreate  = yes
lda_mailbox_autosubscribe = yes
```

to the dovecot's config file.
Sure you have to use dovecot's `deliver` for LDA.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you provision your users, if they're traditional system users the template for the home directory including the Maildir and any other mail folders is `/etc/skel`

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are using `Maildir` in your settings. `Mbox` collects everything in a single file.

The you can follow the steps taken in http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Mail_Server_setup#Create_a_Dovecot-compatible_Maildir_directory_skeleton

The `skel`directory will create new directory in every new user that is added. For users that are already created these directories will have to be created manually (or copied from `skel` after you create them there).